# Coming back in own app after post from Facebook app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, cocoa-touch

I am using the Facebook app installed on my device for posting data on Facebook. I want to come back to my app after clicking and posting on Facebook, but I found no way to do this.  Is there a way?

I am opening the Facebook app on the device through a URL scheme.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Facebook and Apple wouldn't like you modifying the UX of their app and closed ecosystem respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to communicate with Facebook in your own app, you will need to use the Facebook API and program it into your app.  Check  [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/) out for the official Facebook API and directions on how to integrate it into your app.

**Edit:** If you are opening the Facebook App through a URL scheme, you will not be able to return to your own app after.  Doing so would require you to add some code to the Facebook App itself.  I suggest you check out and use the Facebook API.

Comment: I am using URL scheme for opening facebook app. I am not using any facebook sdk. this is need of my app,